# Compare term to current date in HQL (with .Net)

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hql

I want to compare a column value to the current date, using HQL.

I tried

```
IQuery someQuery = session.CreateQuery(String.Format(
            @"Select s.Id
            From InventoryProductStateItem s
            where s.ValidFrom < current_date()"));
```

This throws the exception "Incorrect syntax near keyword current_date()"

current_date does´nt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I used NHibernate, but I think there's a hql function called "current_timestamp" that the various dialect implementations in NHibernate map to their own sql dialect variant.

Failing that, you could always turn it into a parameter.

Comment: don´t know what this current_date is about